# Why does Jquery does not understand dynamic control id with # selector

Tags: jquery

I have a page where my server side button controlid renders as `'_ctl0:btnInsComplete'` but when I try to select my control by syntax `$("#_ctl0:btnInsComplete")`, It returns empty object .When I try with `$("id$='_ctl0:btnInsComplete']")` , It returns the button object. I want to understand why my first syntax is failing even though I am passing complete client side rendered controlid or am I making mistake? Can some one help in this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `:` in button id so you need to escape it.

Use

```
$("#_ctl0\\:btnInsComplete")
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Answer (score 0):

try like this using [Ends with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$("[id$=btnInsComplete]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('button[id="_ctl0:btnInsComplete"]')
```

OR

```
$('[id="_ctl0:btnInsComplete"]')
```